# Trigger action in Phaser with an external button

Tags: typescript, button, phaser-framework

I'm currently facing a problem: I would like to make my player sprite (left character) move to the right one. I already got it working but now I would like to make the character move when I hit the button and here's my problem, I don't know how I can do it.

I already tried with emitters and an external bool.

This is what the html looks: 
[image]

Here's a part of the code

```
    export class CombatComponent implements OnInit {

constructor() { }

public onGameReady(game: Phaser.Game): void {
   this.game = game;
}

public game: Phaser.Game;

public readonly gameConfig: Phaser.Config = {
title: environment.title,
type: Phaser.AUTO,
width: 1024,
height: 512,
physics: {
  default: 'arcade',
  arcade: {
    gravity: {y: 300},
    debug: false
  }
},
scene: {
  preload: function() {
    ...
  },
  create: function () {
   ....
  },
  update: function() {

   ....

  }
}
};

attack() {
 //would like to make my character move here like this.player.x += 1
}
```

If anyone has a solution or tip I would be happy to read it!

Answer (score 0):

Since Phaser is JavaScript, you can add an event listener to the button via standard JavaScript functionality.

In your `create()` you can add the event listener like this:

```
let externalButton =  document.getElementById("yourButtonId");
if (externalButton) {
    externalButton.addEventListener("click", this.attack);
}
```